# The session has been invalidated because the user has changed the password -> no Password was changed

Tags: facebook-graph-api, oauth, passwords

Dear Stackoverflowianers!
Dear Facebook Developers!

I created a Facebook-App couple of weeks ago. In this time it worked perfectly. My PHP-Script checks if the access_token is at least 10 days before expiring (it automatically is set to a long expiration date before) and if so (if >= expiration date - 10) it tries to obtain an new access_token for the same user (which is me, myself and I).

The Problem is that since yesterday it throws me an error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: Error validating access token: The session has been invalidated because the user has changed the password.
```

Now my question is: How can it throw this error as I never changed my password on FB???

Does anybody have any hint for me to the right direction to solve this issue? I'd be very thankful for any help.

Best regards,

AceLine

Comment: Not so much at once!!! ;o)

Comment: I'm with the same problem.. oO how?

Answer (score 0):

Actually there's nothing wrong in your flow. It actually throws that error when the token is expired.

We've experience this kind of error before and what we did was we regularly check that the `accessToken` is still valid if it is not then we generate and save a new one.  However, when we set the `accessToken` that will be used we also extend the life of the token prior to saving it in the local database. See [extendedAccessToken](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-setExtendedAccessToken)

Here's a sample update (This is just a rough code):

```
// Set the access token and extend it
$facebookClient = new FacebookClient();
$facebookClient->setAccessToken($accessToken);
$facebookClient->setExtendedAccessToken();

// Query your user that will have the updated access token and update it.
$user = User::get($userId);
$user->accessToken = $facebookClient->getAccessToken();
$user->update();
```